# Transfering /home to a new partition

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I have one physical hard disk.  Originally, it was partitioned into / and /swap.  Using GParted, I downsized / and created/added a new partition /dev/sda1 as an ext4 partition.

I want to do the following:

```
 1.  Transfer all contents of the original /home to the new partition.

 2.  Establish the new partition as /home for all users (now only 1 regular user plus root user).

 3.  Delete original /home directory.
```

This will leave /home on its own partition.

How do I do this?

Thanking you all in advance, and special thanks to those who told me how to use GParted successfully.

```
       Chaim Frazer
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Beacon?

Seriously, the question has been answered on help.ubuntu.com at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: It may seem clear to you, but not to me.  What does "some settings" mean, and how do I determine if it applies to me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure /dev/sda1 is your new partition? You already had 2 and they were most likely /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2.

Assuming your question is correct and /dev/sda1 is really your new partition you need to mount it and transfer the files. Log off, switch to a text console (Ctrl-alt-F2), log on and:

```
sudo su
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
cd /home
tar cf - * |  tar -C /mnt xpf -
umount /mnt
```

Then rename /home to /old_home
Then add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1  /home    ext4  auto  1   1
```

Then reboot and you should be OK.

Once you are happy that things are working you can delete the old home directory: `sudo rm -rf /old_home`

Comment: You are SO RIGHT.   It's /dev/sda3.  Are all your lines beginning with "sudo su" separate commands?  Also, does the second "tar"command unpack the files?

Comment: Yes, they are separate commands, to be executed in a text-only terminal outside the GUI. Make sure you replace sda1 with sda3, you don't want to damage your sda1! Yes, the second tar command unpacks the files after changing the current directory to the new home and while preserving the ownership and permissions.